# How to use CSS3 to resize table rows

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GCJrd/10/) that hides tables rows.

I am trying to get it to expand the row to `height=200` instead of hiding it.

Feel free to suggest an easier method of doing it (html5, etc) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `toggle()` with two functions as parameters. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). It allows you to define two **or more** functions to cycle through on each mouse click.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//slide up and down when click over id #one
$("#one").toggle(
    function()
        {
        $(".togglebox").height(200);
        },
    function()
        {
        $(".togglebox").height(100);
        });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RNvP4/

Comment: Awesome, this is literally my first venture into jQuery so thanks a ton!