# CSS3 transition on table row using height property

Tags: css, height, loading, css-transitions, tablerow

I have an HTML table displaying some information with a few rows. On each row, the user can click to reveal some additional rows that contains information related to the clicked row.

Something like this:
[image: Deployed rows]

While the additional rows are being created with an AJAX request, a loading row is inserted right after the clicked row :
[image: Loading row]

Currently, everything works perfectly (drill down style), but I would like to add some animation to the loading row.
I found a question ( [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689792/how-to-use-css3-to-resize-table-rows) ) that has a JSFiddle showing kind of what I want ( [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCJrd/10/) ).

I tried to implement something similar with CSS3 transitions, but I can't get it to work.
Here's my simulated attempt ( [fiddle only for deployment of the loading row](http://jsfiddle.net/bjYja/) ) using these transitions :

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: height 0.1s ease-in-out;
```

Any thought on why my fiddle doesn't do any animation?
Any other methods you would propose?

Thanks!

Comment: Just by the way, -ms-transition didn't ever exist other than in an early IE10 beta, and -o-transition isn't really needed either - new versions don't use it. -moz-transition hasn't been needed since Firefox 16. -webkit- is still needed though, and of course the real version!

Comment: I guess that's why they're always in a different color. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear from your question if using CSS transitions is a requirement or not. I went ahead and assumed based off your example jsfiddle that using jQuery instead is acceptable.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjYja/1/) to show this, but basically what I did was remove the CSS transitions and set up new rows to be hidden on load using javascript

```
    loadingRow.className = "deployable";
    jQuery(loadingRow).attr("style","display: none;");
```

Then I use the slideToggle function from your example to ease the new row into place.

```
    loadingRow.style.height = "400px";
    jQuery(loadingRow).slideToggle(2000);
```

Comment: That's interesting, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: It works great, thanks for the reply! I'm not very familiar with jQuery but I'll try playing with this method for the other animations.