# How to animate toggling of table rows?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to animate the appearance and disappearance of table rows.

First of all I tried using a CSS *transition*, but it did nothing due to the change of the `display` property.

So I used an *animation*, which works as expected.

The problem is, **the full height of the row is reserved when the animation begins**. See the snippet below for an illustration of the problem: Row 3 is pushed down straight away, before the animation begins.

**How can I animate the height of the row progressively, so that it only takes as much space as needed?**

And as a bonus:

- it should **not require a fixed height** for rows
- it should appear as a translation, rather than a scaling; it should look like it's **sliding from the bottom of the row above it**
- it should be **bidirectional** (do the opposite when I hide it)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('tr:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
tr {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
  transform-origin: top;
}
tr.active {
  display: table-row;
  animation: anim 0.5s ease;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active">
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you out? ... if no, anything I can improve or clarify?

Comment: @LGSon Sorry for not giving feedback earlier, I was waiting to see if other people would come up with alternative solutions. I'll write my comments on your answer directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 transition on table row using height property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325429/css3-transition-on-table-row-using-height-property)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As `table` `row`/`cell` don't respect a `height` smaller than its content we need to use an inner `div`, we can't animate `display` and we can't animate a `height` set to `auto`, so I here show a solution using `max-height`.

The trick is to give `max-height` a value high enough to enable the highest content.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('tr:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
tr, td {
  padding: 0;
}
tr td div {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s, padding 0.3s;
}
tr.active td div {
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  transition: max-height 0.6s, padding 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td><div>Row 1</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Row 2</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active">
      <td><div>Row 3</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is better than what I came up with, so thanks for this. I can only see 2 small things that could still be improved: the fact that it's not using `display` to properly hide it once completely collapsed (not sure how important this is, but I'm afraid of older browsers, and semantics: using `height:0` to hide an element might not be a best practice); and the fact that it shrinks, instead of looking like it's sliding from the bottom of the row above, which would be my ideal goal!

Comment: @Benjamin Regarding older browsers, consider you use `transition` they are already ruled out. The ideal goal to "slide" down could be done if `height: 0` was able to be set on the `tr`, though it doesn't work, so if you want that, you need to drop the `table` markup and use `div` rows instead, and if you can accept fixed width on each column (since they will not behave as normal cells), that can be achieved.

Comment: Not using a table is not really a solution semantically speaking, as it really is tabular data. As for the older browsers, without the transition, they would still show and hide properly, so that's OK!

Comment: @Benjamin Okay, let me know if I you have any other questions and I'll try suggest a proper fix.

Comment: I guess that's it!

Comment: @Benjamin What is missing to have my answer accepted?

Comment: Are you able to make integrate the changes suggested in my first comment: `display:none` when hidden, and a real sliding effect?

Comment: @Benjamin It is not possible transist `display: none` and by adding it, it make the transition not work, but your worries about `max-height: 0` in older browser, it work down to IE7, so can't see no problem with that. When it comes to the real slide effect, you need `absolute position`, which won't make its parent auto size to content, needing fixed height (or similar) ... so nope, can't help with that ... to over come this you can use jQuery, though older browser support will give issues there as well.

Comment: @Benjamin I also really think, an answer that clearly shows the principle should be good enough to be accepted.

Comment: I do accept answers, in due time :) Thanks for your help, I'll do a bit more research first.

Comment: @Benjamin I never meant you didn't accept nor when that had to be .. hope that is clear :)

Comment: @Benjamin came across this with similar problem. It's still not due time or what? Give that guy’s answer some love :D

Comment: I guess I never accepted it because I was never really satisfied with the result, in particular the fact that it shrinks instead of sliding. But it looks like there is no better solution if I insist on using a table, so let's do this. Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to use CSS3 / support modern browsers you could consider using a `transform:translateY` transition and hide the overflow with `overflow:hidden`.

Do note that Edge / IE do not support the translate transforms on table elements. Chrome does support it.

Comment: Thanks, would you provide a sample code demonstrating this?