# Max-Height Transition

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, transition

well.. I have this problem and it seems that there is no solution out there that will work, it seems like its not even possible to do this in CSS, but I really can't believe it, because its one of those things you should definetly be able to do.

```js
$('logo-toggler').on('click', function(){
    $('#logo-box').toggleClass('no-view');    
});
```

```html
<logo-toggler>Klick to open</logo-toggler>
<br>
<br>
<div id="logo-box" class="no-view">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
```

```css
#logo-box { 
    max-height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.no-view {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    max-height: 0px !important;
}
```

It works fine. The box opens and closes as it should. But here is the first of two problems: If i set the max-height to high, the transition effect isn't smooth, so I have to get the exact height of my text-box everytime I change the text or have another textbox.

That would be okay, if there would be an exact size, but there isn't. If I look at the website from a smaller device, the textbox gets heigher and heigher, until I don't see the full text even if the Box is open.

How is it possible the change the max-height to a dynamic height AND get the transition effect, because transition obviously doesn't work with dynamic heights.

Comment: Check an earlier answer of mine, does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37376274/2827823

Comment: CSS can't (yet) animate a height of auto/dynamic, so the only way is to set the max-height high enough to cover the highest it can be ... or you need to use script (could be the one that toggle the class) and calc and set the height

Comment: see my answer, i solved it using jquery

Comment: @Sharivari only that i revisited this question, I would never have seen your comment. Use the @ tag if you reply to someone. My point was that it's perfectly doable in css. And my fix is better but i will delete it as you obviously are insistent on using jquery despite your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $(function() {   
    
        var name = ('logo');
        var toggler = (name+'-toggler');
        var div = ('#'+name+'-box');
        var toggled_class = ('no-view');        
        var plus_minus_img_id = ('#'+name+'-box-image');
        
        $(toggler).on('click', function(){
            $(div).toggleClass(toggled_class)
            
            var src = ($(plus_minus_img_id).attr('src') === 'http://www.styledesign.de/webpage3/images/plus.png')
            ? 'http://www.styledesign.de/webpage3/images/minus.png'
            : 'http://www.styledesign.de/webpage3/images/plus.png';
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(plus_minus_img_id).attr('src', src);
            }, 500);
            
            
        });

        var height = $(div).outerHeight();
        $(div).css('max-height', height+'px');
        $(div).toggleClass(toggled_class);
})
```

```css
logo-toggler{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell;
}

#logo-box{ 
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#logo-box-image{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.no-view{
    opacity: 0 !important;
    max-height: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<logo-toggler>Logo<img id="logo-box-image" src="http://www.styledesign.de/webpage3/images/plus.png"/></logo-toggler>
                <br>
                <div id="logo-box">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod.
                </div>
```

Well, i solved it, using JQuery:

First, i removed the class "no-view" from the div id, so that it's opened at the start. I also removed the max-height attribute from the #logo-box, so that there is none.

Then I added this script to my code:

```
<script>
    var height = $("#logo-box").outerHeight();
    $("#logo-box").css('max-height', height+'px');
    $('#logo-box').toggleClass('no-view');
</script>
```

I get the height of the div and add it ass max-height to css of #logo-box, no I have everytime the right max-height related to the content.

After that I close the box by adding the class "no-view".

That's it.