# Hide table rows using pure CSS3 in Bootstrap datatable

Tags: html, css, datatable

I use Bootstrap with datatables and would like to hide specific table rows using pure CSS, *without* any JavaScript / jQuery.

I thought, I can do it like this, but it doesn't work, unfortunately:

```css
input[name=hide_rows] + table tr.hide-this-row {
        display: table-row;
}

input[name=hide_rows]:checked + table tr.hide-this-row {
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="hide_rows">Hide rows?</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hide_rows" name="hide_rows" checked>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="some-table" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Head #1</th>
    <th>Head #2</th>
    <th>Head #3</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="show-this-row">
    <td>Row #1</td>
    <td>Row #1</td>
    <td>Row #1</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="hide-this-row">
    <td>Row #2</td>
    <td>Row #2</td>
    <td>Row #2</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr class="show-this-row">
    <td>Row #3</td>
    <td>Row #3</td>
    <td>Row #3</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Please note, that Bootstrap and the datatable is adding some `divs` there and at the end, it has some more HTML tags between.

That's the reason, why I don't would like to use this solution:

```css
input[name=hide_rows] + div > div > div > table tr.hide-this-row {
        display: table-row;
}

input[name=hide_rows]:checked + div > div > div > table tr.hide-this-row {
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
 <label for="hide_rows">Hide rows?</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hide_rows" name="hide_rows" checked>

 <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="some-table" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Head #1</th>
    <th>Head #2</th>
    <th>Head #3</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="show-this-row">
    <td>Row #1</td>
    <td>Row #1</td>
    <td>Row #1</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="hide-this-row">
    <td>Row #2</td>
    <td>Row #2</td>
    <td>Row #2</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr class="show-this-row">
    <td>Row #3</td>
    <td>Row #3</td>
    <td>Row #3</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

I don't like this solution as you have to count and add that much `div`s as there are between and I also had to move the checkbox outside the `<div class="form-group">` and inside the `<div class="table-responsive">`.

It would be much better, if there is an easier solution like the below code for the first shown HTML code:

```css
input[name=hide_rows] + * table tr.hide-this-row {
        display: table-row;
}

input[name=hide_rows]:checked + * table tr.hide-this-row {
        display: none;
}
```

The last CSS code is not working, unfortunately.

Comment: Here's an answer of mine that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375625/how-to-animate-toggling-of-table-rows

Comment: You can't do what you did in your first sample, as for the sibling selector to work, the targeted elements need to be just that, siblings, and a shared parent, and in the first sample they aren't. If you move the `input` outside the first group, and use the general sibling selector `~` instead of the adjacent `+`, it will though.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for not using the JS, because this is just crazy.

Comment: @fvrab Why should I use JS, when it's even possible with CSS only?

Comment: @user2966991 bcs this is really nasty css markup. JS solution will work everywhere without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with minor change in your html. If you move your `table-responsive` div inside the `form-group` below checkbox then you will be able to hide the rows.

Here is a code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="hide_rows">Hide rows?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hide_rows" name="hide_rows" checked/>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="some-table" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Head #1</th>
                <th>Head #2</th>
                <th>Head #3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="show-this-row">
                <td>Row #1</td>
                <td>Row #1</td>
                <td>Row #1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="hide-this-row">
                <td>Row #2</td>
                <td>Row #2</td>
                <td>Row #2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="show-this-row">
                <td>Row #3</td>
                <td>Row #3</td>
                <td>Row #3</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[name=hide_rows] + .table-responsive .hide-this-row {
        display: table-row;
}

input[name=hide_rows]:checked + .table-responsive .hide-this-row  {
        display: none;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
input[name=hide_rows] + .table-responsive .hide-this-row {
        display: table-row;
}

input[name=hide_rows]:checked + .table-responsive .hide-this-row  {
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="hide_rows">Hide rows?</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hide_rows" name="hide_rows" checked/>
  
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="some-table" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Head #1</th>
    <th>Head #2</th>
    <th>Head #3</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="show-this-row">
    <td>Row #1</td>
    <td>Row #1</td>
    <td>Row #1</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="hide-this-row">
    <td>Row #2</td>
    <td>Row #2</td>
    <td>Row #2</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr class="show-this-row">
    <td>Row #3</td>
    <td>Row #3</td>
    <td>Row #3</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/szb4nemk/)

Comment: Thank you for the example and solution!