# null not an object error for expand all/close all

Tags: jquery

Created a table for a client website who would like the tabs to expand and collapse on command. I added an expand/collapse all button but am getting a "null not an object error".

it works perfectly in my HTML editor (Coda) - but when adding to the client website (https://builderincubator.cloudaccess.net/homebuilder-software-table) it does not work.

I am using buttons as such:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="openall">Open All</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" id="closeall">Close All</button>
```

The script is as follows:

```
<script>
    $('table').on('click', 'tr.parent ', function() {
        $(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('#openall').on('click', function() {
        $('tbody').addClass('open');
    });

    $('#closeall').on('click', function(){
        $('tbody').removeClass('open');
    });     
</script>
```

Any thoughts apprecaited.

Comment: Is `$` referring to jQuery, or is it some custom implementation that's supposed to be *like* jQuery? It's strange that when I put something like `$("tbody").length` into console, it returns a `null` error as opposed to just `0`.

Comment: **Update:** After a bit of poking around, this is **not jQuery**; It's **MooTools Core** - specifically the [`$` function](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element#Window:dollar).

Comment: The page in the link does have jQuery in it...twice. That's never going to help. Make sure there's only once instance loaded into the page, otherwise you'll potentially have all sorts of bother

Comment: @ADyson This is true! Although `$` is not referring to either of them :) If you go to the page,   `console.log($)`, and trace that definition, it's coming from `mootools-core.js`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Further investigation reveals that jQuery noConflict is being employed...which can help with the multiple versions (but really, two versions should never be necessary and is not recommended by the jQuery people), but as you say, means jQuery is no longer invoked by the `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` function in your code does *not* refer to jQuery - it refers to the [Mootools Core `$` function](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element#Window:dollar).

If you'd like to use jQuery selectors/functions instead, replace your `$`s with the `jQuery`s.

```
jQuery('table').on('click', 'tr.parent ', function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
});
jQuery('#openall').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('tbody').addClass('open');
});

jQuery('#closeall').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('tbody').removeClass('open');
});
```

---

To confirm/debug:

1. Go to your page
2. Open the console
3. Type `$` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. It returns the function definition for `$`.
5. Click on it - it brings you the source of the definition.
6. Notice the filename: `mootools-core.js`.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your replies! Obviously, I am not a jQuery expert. But I am confused. I am testing this script in a shell HTML document and caling the jQuery library by using   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 - and everything works. The $ is a jquery selector - is it not?

When I delete the link to the jquery library that I added (to negate duplicate jquery) - none of the collapse features work at all?

Comment: I will say that I replaced all the $(s) with jQuery(s) and it did work - even without the second link to the jquery library. I am thoroughly confused now. But thank you for the fix!!!

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can make the rows slide (transition) into view instead of simply flashing on and off as they do?

Comment: With table rows, that can be very tricky, however I've seen it asked elsewhere on Stack Overflow. Check out this link for some helpful advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375625/how-to-animate-toggling-of-table-rows

Comment: Also, you have conflicting libraries. MooTools Core and jQuery both want to use the `$`, however in your example, `MooTools` is likely just defining it *after* jQuery.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. It’s a Joomla site they built but I thought Joomla stopped using Mootools? Oh well. Thx