# How do I get slideUp() to work as intended on a table row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-slide-effects

I have a demo of what I'm trying to explain working in Code Pen here: https://codepen.io/vonroga/pen/gOgWjdj

I have a basic table:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td class="del">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td class="del">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell Contents</td>
            <td class="del">x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using JavaScript/jQuery I want to use the `slideUp()` jQuery animation to hide a table row after clicking on a delete button in that row. However, no animation plays on the table row (see Code Pen linked above).

```js
$('td.del').on('click', e => delCel(e));

function delCel(e) {
  // What I want to work:
  // $(e.target).parent().slideUp(1000);
  // What actually Works:
  $(e.target).parent().hide(1000);
}
```

For `slideUp()`, the animation doesn't play and after the timeout the element just disappears suddenly. At least `hide()` fades the text and cell borders until, once it's hidden, the row pops out of the table abruptly.

So how do I get the table row to slide up, like it's moving under the row above it, and drag the elements in the table below that row up along with it for a smooth animation? My guess is jQuery just isn't quite capable of doing this, so if I have to use something else, I guess that's the way I'll go.

Feel free to suggest a way to do it in CSS/JS instead if that's ultimately easier.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375625/how-to-animate-toggling-of-table-rows That can definitely get you on the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
table,
tr, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  min-height:200px;
}

td.del {
  padding: 3px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but it may not what you expected.